# Is the infinite dihedral group an inverse limit of the finite dihedral groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, dihedral-groups

The [p-adic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number#Algebraic_approach) are the [inverse limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_limit) of the rings $\mathbb Z / p^n \mathbb Z$. Can the infinite dihedral groups be construed as some sort of inverse limit of finite dihedral groups?

Comment: @ZhenLin In what way?

Comment: The p-adics are uncountable, and any interesting inverse limit of dihedral groups will be uncountable as well.

Answer (score 6):

For $n \geq 1$ we have $D_n = \langle x,y : x^n = y^2 = (xy)^2 = 1 \rangle = \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \rtimes \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. For $n|m$ there is a canonical surjective homomorphism $D_m \to D_n$, $x \mapsto x$, $y \mapsto y$. The limit of this diagram is not $D_{\infty} = \langle x,y : y^2 = (xy)^2 = 1 \rangle = \mathbb{Z} \rtimes \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Instead, it is $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}} \rtimes \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, where $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}} = \varprojlim_n \,\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. This is a profinite group which contains $D_{\infty}$ as a dense subgroup.

Answer (score 2):

If "infinite dihedral group" has subgroup $\mathbb Z$, then the answer to the literal question is "no", as is the answer to the modified question (with limit replaced by colimit). In any case, we can see what the plausible limit and colimit really give.

The (projective) limit of $\mathbb Z/n$ with "inverse" adjoined gives $\widehat{\mathbb Z}$ (the product of all $p$-adic integers) with an inverse adjoined.

For the colimit, treat the cyclic case first, map $\mathbb Z/m$ to $\mathbb Z/mn$ by $\ell\mod n\to m\ell \mod mn$. Then take the ascending union of all the $\mathbb Z/n$'s, and we get $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$.
The dihedral case is similar, with an extra "reflection" element tagging along.

Comment: I don't see how that is isomorphic to the infinite dihedral group.

Comment: @PaulPlummer, ah, indeed, if by "infinite dihedral group" is meant just $\mathbb Z$ with a reflection added, it's certainly not... I'll edit...

Comment: @paulgarrett: There is no need to guess, $D_{\infty}$ has a canonical definition, for example as the (nontrivial) semidirect product $\mathbb{Z} \rtimes \mathbb{Z}/2$, or as the isometry group of the discrete metric space $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, oh, yes, you're right, I was just put into a funny state by the question itself! :)